# Concentration of Sub-exponential random Vectors

Tags: pr.probability, real-analysis, stochastic-processes

I was wondering if there is a similar definition of multivariate sub-exponential distribution as the sub-Gaussian case.

Specifically, a random vector $X \in \mathbf{R}^d$ is sub-Gaussian if 
\begin{align}
\sup_{v \in S^{d-1}} \| \langle   v , X \rangle \| _{\psi_2}
\end{align}
is finite.

Can I define sub-exponential vector as $X \in \mathbf{R}^d$  with 
$
\sup_{v \in S^{d-1}} \| \langle   v , X \rangle \| _{\psi_1}
$ bounded?

If so, can I get the Bernstein-type concentration inequality similar to the univariate case for sub-exponential vectors?

Comment: That is how Roman Vershynin defines a sub-exponential vector (see Section 3.4.4 of his book draft http://www-personal.umich.edu/~romanv/papers/HDP-book/HDP-book.html), so it seems a reasonable definition. Do you want concentration for $n^{-1/2}\|\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\|$? If $d$ is fixed, this is basically concentration of $Y^2$ where $Y$ is one of the coordinates (sub-exponential). I don't know off-hand if that gives the worst of "CLT approximation" and "tail of biggest summand". Do you also want the right scaling with $d$, i.e. for coordinates of $X$ to behave as if they're independent?

Comment: Also, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/132678/ is a related question (but has no answers)